# Firebase functions authentication with hosting stripping Authentication header

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, token, firebase-hosting

I have Firebase functions backend rest api and custom domain Firebase hosting pointed to it so I don't lock myself to Firebase provided domain.

At this moment I can reach my backend at 3 urls.

1. `https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/app` - Default url provided by firebase to directly call function.
2. `https://my-project.firebaseapp.com/api` - Default hosting provided by Firebase, rewriting the `/api` source to `app` function.
3. `https://my-custom-domain.com/api` - My custom domain set up in Firebase, rewriting the `/api` source to `app` function.

Now, I can reach my backend on any of these just fine, with one exception. 
I've added an authentication requirement to my functions based on https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint

E.g., my client sends `Authorization: Bearer IdToken`, then Express middleware reads it and verifies it with Firebase Auth.

My problem is that the `Authorization` header is not present in request when the client accesses the backend via 3rd url. The 1st and the 2nd work just fine.

Would anybody know what do I have to configure so the header is forwarded properly?

Thanks

P.S.: This is my hosting configuration:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],    
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special.  Maybe you could show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for both client and server and see if you're doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, the problem was the following:

I own `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`. My Firebase hosting is set to serve from `www` and `mydomain.com` only redirects to `www.mydomain.com`. I've setup clients to call mydomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com. Hence the redirect stripped headers. All I had to do is to point my clients to www.

Comment: Oh Jesus, I wasted so much time trying to figure out why my website wasn't able to authenticate... if I understood this correctly it is because the domains don't match so firebase hosting happily strips the headers to protect me from myself... which is good, but it also does it completely silent which is bad...